# adding RAM diminishes my hard disk space

Tags: windows, hard-drive, memory, default-settings

I have Two Dell Precision 7810 towers, I just upgraded the first one to 256 Gb ram (dual procesor) and all went as expected running windows 10 pro 64 bit.

Now I did the same with the second but I had to stop at 192 Gb because It ran out of hard disk space ? This one was still running on windows 7 utlimate so I thought the OS was the culprit ...

Now I have her running on windows 10 pro 64 bit but the problem remained ... is it a defect, a setting, I cannot find what to do...

with 192 Gb ram I'm alsmost out of hard disk space (500 Gb), anyone has a clue?

Comment: What are the boot drive sizes on each? Check the size of the hiberfil - 256GB RAM is likely to want 256GB hibernation file

Comment: Tetsujin - about 500 Gb ... everything is identical on both computers, why does one claim 256Gb and the other not ?

Comment: Tetsujin - powercfg /hibernate off in the powerShell frees up 150 Gb !!! (i stopped at 192 Gb RAM otherwise the computer doesn't start ...

Comment: testsujin -  thanks you got me thinking this way, I redefined also the virtual memory which can be much lower than 1,5 to 3 times the ram in this case ... why don't you give me a complete answer with all features to check / set and I'll chose it as answer !!

Comment: Glad that set you off in the right direction. I've put both options in the answer. :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding RAM will affect the size of the system's hibernate file `hyberfil.sys`, so 256GB RAM will eat 256GB drive space.

Additionally, the virtual memory will naturally default higher, which probably isn't necessary with so much RAM.

Disabling Hibernate &/or changing the virtual memory size should alleviate the disk usage issue.

Comment: I can only up vote or down vote ... how do I accept the answer?

Comment: There should be a tick [check] mark below the up/down arrows & 'score' to the left. You may have to wait a day before you can accept [I think the timers on that vary depending on how 'new' you are, but I'm not certain]

Comment: ahhh ... that was just too muych time since the last question :-)